# Google Wi-Fi Issues

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook, chromebook

We have issues with certain devices on Google Wi-Fi even though we have three Access Point in a 2,000 SQFT condo.

Some devices appear to have no issues. Chromebooks and Apple MacBooks seem to have the worst issues.

Poor or no transmission (i.e Loading of WebSites) at intermittent times even though the Wi-Fi on the device shows medium connection "Strength".

Anyone else having these issues?

Any Ideas what to look at?

Answer (score 0):

The usual issue when using multiple access points is that more than one is set up to give out IP addresses (i.e. running DHCP) leading to conflicts.  Only one should be the main router.  The other two need to be configured to be signal repeaters only. Where to do this should be covered in the routers' documentation.

Comment: That is how things are configured.